# tensorflow memory consumption keeps increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently optimizing CNN hyperparameters in `tensorflow.keras`, I'm iteratively creating models, training them, logging the results, and scraping them. This works for several hours, allowing me to train over 30 models without failure. However, if I run for long enough, more and more ram is consumed through each iteration, causing a crash. Is there a way to mitigate this

example snippet:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
import datetime
import time

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 15, 32

CONV_QUANTS = [2,4,6]
DENSE_QUANTS = [0,1,2]
DENSE_SIZES = [16,32,64]
KERNAL_SIZES = [3,9,15]
FILT_QUANTS = [16,32,64]
POOL_SIZES = [2,4,6]

testName = 'test_{}'.format(round(time.time()))

for convQuant in CONV_QUANTS:
    for denseQuant in DENSE_QUANTS:
        for denseSize in DENSE_SIZES:
            for kernalSize in KERNAL_SIZES:
                for filtQuant in FILT_QUANTS:
                    for poolSize in POOL_SIZES:
                        
                        #defining name
                        name = 'conv{}_dense{}_dSize{}_kSize{}_filtQuant{}_pSize{}_dt{}'.format(convQuant,
                                                                                                denseQuant,
                                                                                                denseSize,
                                                                                                kernalSize,
                                                                                                filtQuant,
                                                                                                poolSize,
                                                                                                datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
                        print(name)

                        #defining log
                        logdir = os.path.join("logs",testName,name)
                        tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)

                        #initializing model
                        model = Sequential()
                        
                        #input convolutional layer
                        model.add(Conv1D(filters=filtQuant, kernel_size=kernalSize, activation='relu', input_shape = trainX[0].shape))
                        model.add(Dropout(0.1))
                        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=poolSize))
                        
                        #additional convolutional layers
                        for _ in range(convQuant-1):
                            model.add(Conv1D(filters=filtQuant, kernel_size=kernalSize, activation='relu'))
                            model.add(Dropout(0.1))
                            model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=poolSize))
                        
                        #dense layers
                        model.add(Flatten())
                        
                        for _ in range(denseQuant):
                            model.add(Dense(denseSize, activation='relu'))
                            model.add(Dropout(0.5))
                            
                        #output
                        model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
                        
                        #training
                        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
                        model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, validation_data=(testX, testy), callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
                        
                        #calculating accuracy
                        _, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
                        accuracy = accuracy * 100.0
                        print('accuracy: {}'.format(accuracy))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating many models in a loop, this global state will consume an increasing amount of memory over time, and you may want to clear it. Calling clear_session() releases the global state: this helps avoid clutter from old models and layers, especially when memory is limited.

```
for _ in range(100):
  # Without `clear_session()`, each iteration of this loop will
  # slightly increase the size of the global state managed by Keras
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(10) for _ in range(10)])

for _ in range(100):
  # With `clear_session()` called at the beginning,
  # Keras starts with a blank state at each iteration
  # and memory consumption is constant over time.
  tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(10) for _ in range(10)])
```

For more details about this library can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session)